# Google Maps Polygone "clickable: false" shows no effect

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm working with the google maps API-v3. I'm adding a polygone to my map and a bunch of Polylines. These lines are usually located within the area of the polygones. This looks like so:
[image: Map with polygon and polylines]

I disabled the click-event on the polygone:

```
let mapPolygone = {
            id: currentPolygone.Id, //currentPolygone is just a wrapper
            path: path,
            stroke: {
              color: currentPolygone.LineColor,
              weight: currentPolygone.LineWeight
            },
            fill: {
              color: currentPolygone.FillColor,
              opacity: currentPolygone.Opacity
            },
            editable: false,
            draggable: false,
            geodesic: false,
            // I disabled the click
            clickable: false,
            visible: true,
          }
```

I registered a click-handler on the polyine:

```
let mapPolyline = {
    // currentPolyline is also a wrapper
    id: currentPolyline.Id,
    path: path,
    stroke: {
      color: currentPolyline.LineColor,
      weight: currentPolyline.LineWeight
    },
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    editable: false,
    draggable: false,
    geodesic: false,
    clickable: true,
    visible: true,
    icons: this.getIcons(currentPolyline), // generates a standard GMap-Arrow
    events: {
      //Here goes the click event. Doing stuff on 
      click: (polyline: any) => {
        this.$scope.polyLineClicked(currentPolyline.Id);
      }
    }
  }
```

What I expect from google, and from another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14252677/disable-click-on-polygon), is that the polygone ignores the click and whathever element is below the polyline gets the click.
However, this is not the case. I still get the click-cursor when being above the polygone

[image] [image]

and it still gets the click.

The order of drawing polylines/polygones happens in random order. Sometimes the line is clickable (when painted above the polygone), but usually it's not.

Is there any way to get this working without coming up with custom overlays and things like that?
Am I missing something here?

Thank you folks in advance!

Comment: If you don't draw any polylines, the polygon's not clickable?  Can we see a full example demonstrating how you're creating the polygon and polylines?

Comment: Is it impossible to change the order of the overlays (I think this would by far be the most effective and easy solution that I can think of)?  Looking at your other thread, you could store all the data in 2 arrays (one containing polylines, one containing polygons); then at the last moment you set the polygons on the map, then the polylines

Comment: @EmmanuelDelay: I guess that is not possible, as google maps uses a fixed layer system in which polylines and polygones are drawn into the same layer (See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15674284/2221750)

Answer (score 0):

Alright, preparing the MWE, recommended by @duncan did the trick.
I'm using the [angular-google-map](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/) package, which provides an angular wrapper for the Google Maps API.

Polylines and Polygones are being passed to a directive:

```
 <ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' 
                     zoom='map.zoom' 
                     options="map.options" 
                     aria-label="Google map"                     
                     control="map.control"
                     events="map.events" 
                     refresh="refresh">
    <!-- Polylines-->
    <ui-gmap-polyline ng-repeat="p in mapPolylines" 
                      path="p.path" 
                      stroke="p.stroke" 
                      visible="p.visible"
                      geodesic="p.geodesic" 
                      fit="true" 
                      editable="p.editable" 
                      icons="p.icons"  
                      draggable="p.draggable" 
                      events="p.events">
    </ui-gmap-polyline>

    <!-- Polygones -->
    <ui-gmap-polygon ng-repeat="p in mapPolygones" 
                     path="p.path" 
                     stroke="p.stroke" 
                     fill="p.fill" 
                     visible="p.visible"
                     geodesic="p.geodesic" 
                     fit="true" 
                     editable="p.editable" 
                     draggable="p.draggable" 
                     events="p.events">
    </ui-gmap-polygon>
</ui-gmap-google-map>
```

I missed adding the "clickable" attribute to the *ui-gmap-polygon* tag. When adding this snipped to the tag, everything worked like a charm:

```
clickable="p.clickable"
```

Thank you guys anyways.

Answer (score 0):

For poly* stack ordering, you could also use [the zIndex property](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PolylineOptions), which specifies "The zIndex compared to other polys". The angular-google-maps package also provides the option to set [the zIndex attribute](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/blob/cbd17a3a225dfe543faa124eb295e66db566f27c/src/coffee/directives/api/i-polyline.coffee#L18).